# Delphi: convert TDate to other format

Tags: delphi, date, time, tdatetime

```
var MyDate:TDate; 
   MyDate:=Date;
```

How can I convert local myDate to my format: 31/12/2011?

`RecodeDate`?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [`FormatDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FormatDateTime) function in your case you try this

```
FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',MyDate);
```

Comment: :) Thanks, why nothing was said about that function here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Date_and_Time_Support ?

Comment: @Maxfax - good question. It is in [Type conversion routines](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_conversion_routines), but a second reference would be good

Comment: Depending on your (and your clients) requirements, it may be better to use DateToStr(MyDate), as this will follow the current users locale settings, e.g. mm/dd/yyyy for US users, dd/mm/yyyy for UK etc. American software that always uses mm/dd/yy annoys (and confuses) me, so I try to extend the same courtesy that I would like.

Comment: there are some variables which contain the current date locales. see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.ShortDateFormat